# Onbeforeunload как узнать страницу перехода пользователя?

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью onbeforeunload узнать куда собирается перейти пользователь? Просто модальное окно выдается даже при отправки формы, как можно поправить?

**Обновление**

Все сделал так - на форму повесил  onsubmit="window.onbeforeunload = null;". И все отлично заработало, спасибо =) Но все равно я не смог найти как узнать куда переходит пользователь.

**Обновление 2**

В хроме у меня нет такого свойства, а в лисе есть. А по поводу информации перехода, то жалко, что нельзя узнать. Просто тоже не совсем адекватно вешать события при клике, чтобы снять onbeforeunload. Просто хорошо, что только на одну форму необходимо повесить, а если было бы несколько разных тегов, то беда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед отправкой формы (в событии submit отключайте beforeunload) или  мб (я не проверял в параметре event перехватчика события что-то есть)

**Обновление**

Куда переходит - никак (в общем случае - приватная инфа), в event есть свойство `explicitOriginalTarget`, которое указывает на объект куда ткнули, но, мне кажется, оно не очень стандартное.

Comment: Тему думаю можно закрывать. @eicto, спасибо большое =)